# Invalid syntax with setx

Tags: windows, environment-variables, ogre

I used the `setx` command to set `OGRE_HOME`:

```
setx OGRE_HOME D:\Program Files\OgreSDK
```

Now I need to change to value of `OGRE_HOME`.
How can I search all the values I have set?
If I run the command again, it shows that:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
```

Comment: Not sure to understand but to see all values, use `set`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your path to the Ogre SDK has a space character in it, which is interpreted as a delimiter to another argument. Surround your path with `"` to keep it as one single argument to `setx`:

```
setx OGRE_HOME "D:\Program Files\OgreSDK"
```

To see the current value of the `OGRE_HOME` environment variable:

```
echo %OGRE_HOME%
```

You may have to open a new command prompt shell to see the value if you set it and are then trying to immediately see it's value.

To see all currently set environment variables, simply run:

```
set
```

To show only environment variables that have a certain prefix (so `FOO` would show `FOOBAR` and `FOOBAZ`), put that prefix after `set`:

```
set PREFIX
```

Alternatively, you can use the GUI to edit environment variables (assuming Windows 7 here).

- Right-click `Computer`, choose `Properties`
- Click `Advanced system settings` in the left pane
- Make sure you're on the `Advanced` tab in the pop-up dialog
- Click `Environment Variables...` at the bottom

A dialog will pop up with your user-specific environment variables as well as your system-wide environment variables. Select a value and use the New/Edit/Delete buttons to interact with them.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I will never install software at path with space character, because it may catch some trouble that we are hard to check.

Comment: Note that you also need "" if you're using %PATH% (for appendages).

Answer (score 4):

Command Prompt is giving you that error because you forgot the quotation marks. You should’ve typed:

```
setx OGRE_HOME "D:\Program Files\OgreSDK"
```

To see all the values you’ve already set, enter either:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
```

OR

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

Answer (score 2):

setx and pretty much all windows command line commands are sensitive to certain special characters. Among them the space character but there's also the quote which is used to delimit an entry.

As @ajp15243 already said, you can deal with the space by locking off the path{s) between two quotations. But what if you have paths and those path already have quotations because they carry a space? Here's an example:

```
MY_PATHS="c:\Program Files\path1";"c:\Program Files(x86)\Path2"
```

In this case, you would have to put escape characters for those inner quotation marks when you use setx or it will get confused and give the error you listed. Eg:

```
setx -m MY_PATHS "\"c:\Program Files\path1\";\"c:\Program Files(x86)\Path2\""
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [@ajp15243's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215799/1519199).  If you are doing the same with PowerShell rather than the command prompt or batch file, you'll need to call `SETX` with a leading escaped double-quote character, as in:

```powershell
$my_path = "%PROGRAMFILES%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"
$hkcu_path = (Get-ItemProperty hkcu:\Environment).PATH + ";" + $my_path
SETX PATH "`"$hkcu_path" # note the leading escaped quote
```

However doing so, may result in adding a **trailing** double quote in the value of `hkcu:\Environment\PATH`, so you may need to do this too:

```powershell
$dirty_path = (get-itemproperty hkcu:\Environment).PATH
$clean_path = $dirty_path -replace '"',''
SETX PATH $clean_path
```