# Environment variable behavior in Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have a question regarding environment variables in Windows. So, I set an environment variable using SETX command:

```
SETX my_var VAR
```

After that, I use **SET m** to see if my variable is set. It shows it isn't. However, the variable appears in **HKCU\Environment**. I exit the command prompt window and open a new one. Typing **SET m** again makes my variable appear.
I restart **explorer.exe** and open a new command prompt window. When using **SET m**, my variable isn't there anymore, but it is in **HKCU\Environment**.

I don't understand this behavior. Shouldn't it appear also after restarting **explorer.exe**, giving the fact that it is still in **HKCU\Environment**? I am missing something, I just don't understand what.

**Later edit:** I have tried doing the same thing on a computer running Windows 7 and I found out there is no problem. Don't know what is wrong in my case. I want anyway to thank everybody for their help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I retrieve a value after using setx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059311/how-do-i-retrieve-a-value-after-using-setx)

Comment: I've already done that (opening another command prompt window - it is working indeed). My problem is why it is not working anymore after restarting explorer.exe?

Comment: try using `/m` : /m
Specifies to set the variable in the system environment. The default setting is the local environment.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but it is still not working.

Comment: did you ran it within an elevated command prompt ?

Comment: I ran it with Administrator privileges. Is it this what you are referring to?

Comment: yes that was my question

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on windows 8.1
What windows version are you on?

Comment: 8.1 pro for me too. I am seeing the exact same things you see. However, after restarting explorer i do see my_var when executing set m in a cmd box. You're pc/user account is not on some policy that resets the env variables?

Comment: That I do not know [not my personal home computer]. But if it were, shouldn't the variable no longer appear in HKCU\Environment after restarting explorer.exe? I will investigate on your remark anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`setx` sets the variable for `future` sessions, not any existing session (including this one).

No-one ever claimed that there was any logical reason for the 'not this one' quirk. It's eacy to overcome though - just add **SETXX.BAT** somewhere on your path

**SETXX.BAT**

```
SETX %1 %2
set "%1=%2"
```

and execute it as

```
call SETXX my_var VAR
```

(you may need to play around with quotes if you are attempting to `set`(x) a value containing spaces)

Comment: Still not working. Restarting explorer.exe is the problem, although I cannot see why this is happening.