# How to change the value of pre-existing permanent variable using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Look at the code below! You will understand what I want:

```
@echo off
setx myname king
echo %myname%
setx myname Queen
echo %myname%
```

Output:

```
king
king  //Why did it not change?? whats wrong? and how to change?
```

I even tried it after deleting the varable by :

```
REG delete HKCU\Environment /F /V myname
```

But still the output don't change!!

Comment: `Setx` doesn't affect the current environment but future ones. Use `set` AND `setx`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I retrieve a value after using setx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059311/how-do-i-retrieve-a-value-after-using-setx)

Comment: but still it fail to change!!

Comment: You aren't using `set` so it will never work.