# Invalid syntax with "setx" for having more than two arguments when there are only two arguments

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, windows-8.1, setx

I'm having trouble setting the global environment variable `PATH` permanently with `SETX`.

I've read the answers on similar questions such as [Invalid syntax with setx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215799/2886326) as well as read the syntax on [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).

As far as I know, the following line follows the syntax of `SETX` correctly and does **NOT** have more than two arguments in it:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%"
```

But that doesn't stop `SETX` from giving me this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

The above command was **run on an administrator instance of `cmd.exe`**. What makes the problem all the more stranger is that **on a user instance of `cmd.exe` the same command works perfectly.**

I simplified the above command to emphasize the problem, but what I'm really trying to run is:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin" /M
```

Of course, this gives the same exact error, and I can't run it on a user instance of `cmd.exe` because I'm trying to set the global environment variable `PATH` permenantly. (which needs administrator access)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 echo %PATH%
```

If your (machine level) `%path%` ends with a trailing `\` reverse solidus (*backslash*), you should double it as follows:

```
if "%path:~-1%"=="\" (
   SETX PATH "%PATH%\"
) else (
   SETX PATH "%PATH%"
)
```

Resource: [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) (note my own highlights in following citation):

> Some commands (e.g. `REG` and `FINDSTR`) use the standard escape character
>   of `\` (as used by C, Python, SQL, bash and many other languages.) The `\`
>   escape can cause problems with quoted directory paths that contain a
>   trailing backslash because the closing quote `"` at the end of the line
>   will be escaped `\"`.
>
> To save a directory path with a trailing backslash (`\`) requires adding
>   a second backslash to *'escape the escape'* so for example instead of
>   `"C:\My Docs\"` use `"C:\My Docs\\"`

Above statements on trailing `\` applies to  **`SETX`** as well. Here's an example:

```
==>set myPath
myPath=D:\Program Files\OgreSDK\

==>setx myOgre "%myPath%"
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myOgre
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    myOgre    REG_SZ    D:\Program Files\OgreSDK"

==>setx myOgre "%myPath%\"
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myOgre
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    myOgre    REG_SZ    D:\Program Files\OgreSDK\

==>
```

The `Invalid syntax` error relates to broken user level `%PATH%` variable caused by first using of `SETX PATH "%PATH%"` as user level environment variable takes precedence over machine level one. To solve the problem, adjust user level `%PATH%` variable (or remove it at all) first [via Windows GUI (preferred)](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html):

`Control Panel | System | Advanced | Environment Variables`

**Proof - reproduce the problem** in two steps:

Step #1: start with good `%myPath%` variable on machine level with trailing `\`; lastly (in fine) broke this variable for current user level and `exit` the `cmd` session.

```
==>set myPath
myPath=D:\temp\foo foo\

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myPath
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

==>reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"  /v myPath
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
    myPath    REG_SZ    D:\temp\foo foo\

==>setx myPath "%myPath%;D:\temp\bu bu bu"
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myPath
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    myPath    REG_SZ    D:\temp\foo foo\;D:\temp\bu bu bu

==>rem fetch erroneous state
==>setx myPath "%myPath%"
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myPath
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    myPath    REG_SZ    D:\temp\foo foo"

==>exit
```

Step #2: in a new `cmd` session, start with broken `%myPath%` variable on user level with trailing `"`; this raises the error described in question.

```
==>set myPath
myPath=D:\temp\foo foo"

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myPath
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    myPath    REG_SZ    D:\temp\foo foo"

==>reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"  /v myPath
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
    myPath    REG_SZ    D:\temp\foo foo\

==>setx myPath "%myPath%;D:\temp\bu bu bu"
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.

==>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v myPath
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    myPath    REG_SZ    D:\temp\foo foo"

==>
```

Comment: Actually, I'm sure it ends with a `;`, if not then with the end of a folder name, but definitely not with a \. Also, at the time of writing, there didn't exist a `PATH` variable on the user level.

Answer (score 3):

Below worked for me:

**Step 1:**

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;%GOPATH%bin"
```

I got the following response:

```
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.  

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

Another simpler example could be:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Go\bin"
```

**Step 2:**

Restart the command line, to see the new path settings

```
echo %PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

It means it is already in the path (I've been fighting setx for several days, it is stupid).

You can add an same existing entry or add an new entry without error, but not a different entry. Path is blank per user, path is not blank per machine.